# EE3 Control Panel entry form page layout - 2 columns gone?

Tags: control-panel, ee3

I've just set up my first EE3 site after having produced many sites using EE2. Aside from the learning curve of a new control panel, a feature clients used to love was the ability to 'design' their entry forms (i.e. layout, ordering, columns). I've found the ability to 'order' fields, but it seems you can no longer 'shorten' the fields to enable the page to have 2 columns?

ie. I used to have a half / half split column with 'title' on the left and then 'url title' beside it on the right. Likewise for setting 3 images I'd have 3 smaller columns for them rather than 3 single full-width 'rows'.

Am I missing something or is that no longer possible?

Christiaan

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the "Digi Nut Control Panel CSS & JS" plugin to adjust the css to something more like EE2.

For example, I have a very wide screen, and adding this css made the template editing window stretch wider than the default and made the left column on the Edit windows take up less room than the right column. The layout functionality of EE3 is still not near as flexible as EE2, but this helped me.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.col-group { max-width:90%; }
.w-8 { width:30% }
.w-8.last { width:70% }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As EE3 is all about bootstrap responsive concept, Its not possible till now. may be they add this feature in upcoming version of EE3.

Comment: I've create a feature request (and poll) @
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/249245/

Comment: Good idea. I voted to :)